# How to adjust the height of bg image and label image?

Tags: css, layout, background, background-image

How to adjust the height of bg image and label image? Here's output that I need and here's the [site](http://www.homecredit.ph/2177-2/) that I need to adjust the navigation. I try to use height:[no.of px] but the output of this is not what I need.

And when I try to enlarge the label image, the image is going to overflow to the bg image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need the `background-size` property applied to the relevant elements.

See reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size

Also, you can write the CSS rule more consisely using the shorthand notation,
that is, the `background` property.

You may also need to apply the `background-clip` property.

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  height: 150px;
  width: 450px;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/1000/500);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 50px;
  background-position: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>Sample text. Original image is 1000x500 px, but displayed as 100x50px.</div>
```